# do-while loop wont exit in C

Tags: c, do-while

Ok, I'm sorry in advance, I know there is a thousand examples of how do-while loops work and how to exit them. I swear I've tried them all. For the life of me, I cannot get this to exit when the user enters a 0. There has to be something I'm over-looking. How I got the one to work inside the else if loop but the main one is beyond me.  I would appreciate any help or direction.

```
int main()
{
    char connectBoard[6][7];
    int i , j;
    char c;
    int turn = 1;
    char player1 = 'x';
    char player2 = 'o';
    int spot;

    for( i = 0; i < 6; i++) //sets up 2D array board
    {
        for( j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            c = '.';
            connectBoard[i][j] = c;
        }
    }
    for( i = 0; i < 6; i++)// prints out 2D array board
    {
        for( j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", connectBoard[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("=======\n");
    printf("1234567\n");

    do{
        if( turn%2 != 0 ) //player1 turn
        {
            for( i = 5; i < 6; i++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < 1; j++)
                {
                    printf(" Player %c, drop your piece in which column (1-7 or 0 to quit): ", player1);
                    scanf("%d", &spot);
                    j = spot - 1;
                    if( connectBoard[i][j] == '.' )
                    {
                        connectBoard[i][j] = 'x';
                    }
                    else if( connectBoard[i][j] == 'x' || connectBoard[i][j] == 'o' )
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            i--;
                        }while(connectBoard[i][j] == 'x' || connectBoard[i][j] == 'o');
                        connectBoard[i][j] = 'x';
                        if( i == -1 )
                        {
                            printf("***Bad entry, try again: ");
                            scanf("%d", &spot);
                            j = spot - 1;
                            i = 5;
                            connectBoard[i][j] = 'x';
                        }
                    }
                    turn++;
                }
                break;
            }
            printf("\n");
            for( i = 0; i < 6; i++)// prints out 2D array board
            {
                for( j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                {
                    printf("%c", connectBoard[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("=======\n");
            printf("1234567\n");
        }
        if( turn%2 == 0 ) //player2 turn
        {
            for( i = 5; i < 6; i++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < 1; j++)
                {
                    printf(" Player %c, drop your piece in which column (1-7 or 0 to quit): ", player2);
                    scanf("%d", &spot);
                    j = spot - 1;
                    if( connectBoard[i][j] == '.' )
                    {
                        connectBoard[i][j] = 'o';
                    }
                    else if( connectBoard[i][j] == 'x' || connectBoard[i][j] == 'o' )
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            i--;
                        }while(connectBoard[i][j] == 'x' || connectBoard[i][j] == 'o');
                        connectBoard[i][j] = 'o';
                        if( i == -1)
                        {
                            printf("***Bad entry, try again: ");
                            scanf("%d", &spot);
                            j = spot - 1;
                            i = 5;
                            connectBoard[i][j] = 'o';
                        }
                    }
                    turn++;
                }
                break;
            }
            printf("\n");
            for( i = 0; i < 6; i++)// prints out 2D array board
            {
                for( j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                {
                    printf("%c", connectBoard[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("=======\n");
            printf("1234567\n");
        }

    }while( spot != 0 );




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do while?
Use a simple While in a function an do a return or break.
In my opinion do while should be avoid as much as possible.
And please stop using printf like this, this is awfull, buffering etc.... read printf man :)

Comment: `j = spot - 1;` when `spot` is `0` address the matrix out of bound, so [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: BTW the `printf` that ask for `0` to exit is inside a double for loop. You must exits both to kill the external while loop.

Comment: This code is needlessly complex. You should break it down into functions. As a side-effect, that will probably cause most problems to go away.

Comment: The do-while loop is hard to follow since it contains so many statements. Define a function for "player turn" and call it for each player. That way you also avoid code duplication.

Comment: @pix I originally had just a while loop, but that wasn't working for me either :/ and I'm just learning C, i promise to avoid printf as soon as I'm taught it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the spot variable, you can check if the value is 0 and break:

```
   printf(" Player %c, drop your piece in which column (1-7 or 0 to quit): ", player2);
   scanf("%d", &spot);
   if (spot == 0)
     return 1;
   j = spot - 1;
```

and change your do while to a while loop to avoid confusion.

Comment: ah yes, in that case we can exit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable only for that loop. You are using spot inside your loop to do other things, use it only for the while purpose.

Then, you know the diference between do/while and while? I dont understand very well your program, but if you are reading a spot, you can read it at beggining and outside the loop and then check it with a while loop. Its the same but maybe its more easy for you.

Comment: ok, so I see what you mean by using a different variable for the while loop, but then how would the user choose 0 to quit? If I'm understanding right, I think I may have tried that already. I made another variable called end, then set it to equal whatever the user input for spot, and used just a while loop to see if end was equal to 0, which also didn't work for me.  Its a program to play connect 4.

Comment: Then why if the player enter 0 you dont turn end into the while exit condition?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using spot for while loop. as per C language, It stores a garbage value.

Even if you use, please do not set values to it. Please check basic C variables declaration.

Comment: Mainly right, but in this specific case the loop is a `do-while`, so `spot` is inited by internal loops.